# changing ID of link

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty changing the ID of this link on the fly with jquery.  I can change the link text, but not the ID.  Any ideas?

```
<a href="#" id="follow-5">follow</a>
```

and when you click the link, i'd like for it to look like:

```
<a href="#" id="following-5">following</a>
```

here is my jquery code

```
$("a[id^='follow']").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var aid = $(this).attr('id').substring(7);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "/artist/", data: "command=becomeFan&aid=" + aid,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            $("#follow-" + aid).text("Following");
            $("#follow-" + aid).prev("a").attr("id","following-" + aid);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem is your code doesn't try to change the id of *that* element, it tries to change the id of the `.prev()` element. So change:

```
$("#follow-" + aid).prev("a").attr("id","following-" + aid);
```

to:

```
$("#follow-" + aid).attr("id","following-" + aid);
```

And it should work. But given you've already selected the same element on the line before you should just chain the `.attr` call:

```
        $("#follow-" + aid).text("Following")
                           .attr("id","following-" + aid);
```

Or rather than reselected the element by id, save a reference to it before making the Ajax call:

```
$("a[id^='follow']").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        aid = $this.attr('id').substring(7);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "/artist/", data: "command=becomeFan&aid=" + aid,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            $this.text("Following").attr("id","following-" + aid);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note also that your use of the attribute starts with selector with `$("a[id^='follow']")` will continue to select those elements even after their id is changed, but using `.substring(7)` to get the id from the end will *not* work after you change the id. You might want to change that to `$("a[id^='follow-']")` so the click handler only works on the links not already clicked.